# Why does adding the float property make my divs behave like inline-block?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have two divs with two main properties display block and width

```css
#block1 {
display:block;
width:20%;
background-color:red;
height:100px;
}

#block2 {
display:block;
width:70%;
background-color:yellow;
height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block1">
</div>

<div id="block2">
</div>
```

when I add float propery it makes the two divs behave like an inline-block :

```css
#block1 {
display:block;
width:20%;
float:left;
background-color:red;
height:100px;
}

#block2 {
display:block;
width:70%;
float:left;
background-color:yellow;
height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block1">
</div>

<div id="block2">
</div>
```

Why adding the property float:left makes the div behave like an inline-block

Comment: Think about it like, floating is actually letting the other things float around it. They aren't behaving like inline-block elements. I embraced floats - but I haven't used one in years now. Check out flex-box / if you can ditch IE 10

Comment: divs are block-level elements by default, therefore no need for display: block

Comment: Okay, i was using inline-flex, but i heard it is not supported on my favorite browser until v11, so i am trying to find out other basic solutions

Comment: @VXp yes i know right , i just wanted to point out to make the question more clear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) takes the elements out of the normal document flow in a way that other `inline` elements can wrap around them; it does not make them behave like `inline-block` elements.

If you would like alternative ways to achieve the same effect, give a look at the following examples.

**Example 1:**

Here's an example using `display: flex` on the parent element to make the children stay on the same line.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

#block1 {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}

#block2 {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="block2"></div>
```

**Example 2:**

Here is an example using `display: inline-block` on both elements to make them stay on the same line. Also, `font-size: 0` is used on the parent to ensure that the gap in-between vanishes.

```css
body {
  font-size: 0;
}

#block1 {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}

#block2 {
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="block2"></div>
```

**Example 3:**

Here is an example using `display: table-cell` on both elements to make them stay on the same line, while `display: table` is used on the parent.

```css
body {
  width: 90%;
  display: table;
}

#block1 {
  width: 22.2222222%;     /* 20% of 90% */
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}

#block2 {
  width: 77.7777778%;     /* 70% of 90% */
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="block2"></div>
```

Comment: thank you. Do you use float property to make two divs goes on the same line with different width ? is it a good practice ?

Comment: You're welcome @MehdiSouregi. Generally, in order to accomplish what you want I use either `display: inline-block` on all elements or `display: flex` on their parent to make all of them stay on the same line.

Comment: yes sometimes inline-block does not make the divs "aligned" , so i need to swap to inline-flex , and flex box is not supported untill IE11

Comment: What do you mean `"aligned"`? You can always use `vertical-align` to ensure the elements are aligned however you want.

Comment: sometimes one div can contains more text than the second one , in this case the divs does not stay on the same line with inline-block like you said, so i need to swap to inline-flex, and i am trying to avoid flex cuz it is not supported until IE11

Comment: There's also the option of using `display: table-cell` on your elements while using `display: table` on their parent. This way the elements will always stay inline @MehdiSouregi.

Comment: worked thank you, last question which solution do you prefer , the table-cell or using the float property ?

Comment: It depends on the use @MehdiSouregi. If I want a piece of text to float around an image in an article I use `float`. In your case, if `flexbox` is unavailable I use `display: table-cell`.

Answer (score 2):

A floated element is removed from the normal flow of the document (but not exactly like an absolutely-positioned element).

That's why the next element moves to the top row and sits next to the floated element.

If you want the next element to stay at the bottom row, you need to use the `clear` property.

```css
#block1 {
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}

#block2 {
  clear: both; /* NEW */
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="block2"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in saying that this particular situation `float` behaves *like* `inline-block`. But in reality it just looks like it's behaving the same way. To show the difference... let's say you were to `float:left` with some text below it: then your div would appear to the left and the remaining available horizontal room would be filled with the text.

With float:

```css
.floatie {
    float:left;
    width:170px;
    height:170px; 
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <div class="floatie"></div>consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>
```

But then if you `display:inline-block` you get a different result:

```css
.floatie {
    display:inline-block;
    width:170px;
    height:170px; 
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <div class="floatie"></div>consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>
```

Comment: very good explanation, now i can see the difference between the two , thank you

Answer (score 1):

Adding the property `left` to your div's css haven't made them as `inline-block`. It has made them **floated** in the DOM.